# DirectLine api for power virtual agent bot returns null as the conversatin id

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am trying to communicate with a Bot built via Power Virtual Agent bot using the "Mobile App" channel [as per connect to bot github code](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/power-platform/blob/main/power-virtual-agents/publication-connect-bot-to-custom-application.md) .

I am able to get the token allright but the line sometimes returns null

```
var conversation =  await directLineClient.Conversations.StartConversationAsync();
```

It is a Power Virtual Agent Bot that i am trying to connect to ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rather than using token in directline constructor, I used the secret and its working fine now.
In my case the code is C# running at server so using token isnt an issue thing will be complicated if you are using directline in client side and only option is token then

Answer (score 0):

The Direct Line Connector package and the documentation you're using are quite outdated. You will find better success connecting to Direct Line through REST API calls, as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) for Direct Line v3.0.

Comment: thanks Ap01 but i am already using Directline 3.0.2.

Comment: Yes, but you're using the old Connector package to communicate with it. You should instead be using an HTTP client package.